# How to integrate amazon chime sdk in Angular?

Tags: angular, aws-chime-sdk

I am new in angular and having a task to integrate amazon chime sdk in an existing angular application. I have tried demos of chime sdk provided in git repository, but not able translate in my angular application. If anyone can provide me any working demo code of amazon chime written in angular then it would be great.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We are not here to do the work for you. Better to write the code and if you get stuck on specific issues, ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly do React and not Angular, but there are some other examples of how to set up an Amazon Chime SDK Meeting with React that might help: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-media-capture-pipeline-demo

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully integrate amazon-chime in angular 13. I've build a basic audio-video meeting demo. If you need help I can guide as per my knowledge

Comment: yes please i do need help to integrate it with my angular app

Comment: OK, I can help. Tell me what did you try and where did you got stuck?